# How can i get privilege access for uber-api to book rides and track rides

Tags: uber-api

How can i get privilege access for uber-api to book rides and track rides as access is still in pending state on uber developer platform. without this booking are in processing state only.
Kindly help

Comment: I sthis the right place to ask for access privileges of a commercial vendors platform? I doubt that.

Answer (score 1):

There is an access request form under which you can request this ability for your app. Here are resources with more information: https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/scopes

"Steps to Request Full Access

- Sign In to the Developer Dashboard
- Click the Authorization tab
- Click Request Full Access next to the privileged scope
- Provide as much information about your app as possible
- Submit the request"

I believe in your case we followed up directly asking for more information before the access can be granted. Please follow up via that thread if you have more questions. Thanks.

Comment: Where to include the videos and screenshots for requesting full access?

Comment: In the reply to the email include links to screenshots or video (e.g. imgur, youtube, google drive if you want things to be private, etc.) whatever hosting service you prefer.

Comment: @KyleDavis We have followed the same steps that you mentioned here. First time "request full access" turned to  "full access pending" then again "request full access". Now we resubmitted with more details the status is  "full access pending". How long it will take to get the full access. Is there any change in this procedure or we have to do anything else?